# How do you get a pager to work with the Dynamic View Panel?

Tags: xpages

I have created a Dynamic View Panel custom control and want to add a pager to it.  When I drop a pager into the designated editable area, I get `Pager is not associated with any data control.`  I am computing the datasource using a sessionScope variable.

I've gone into All Properties and added the following code in the `For` property:

```
if(sessionScope.clickedView == null){
    return "All Active/All By Acronym";
}else{
    return sessionScope.clickedView;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

MJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of the for attribute should match the id attribute of the view panel.

Answer (score 3):

Just incase you were curious wht it would look like, I had one up so here is an example.

```
<xe:dynamicViewPanel rows="30" id="dynamicViewPanel1">
    <xe:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="alldocs"></xp:dominoView>
    </xe:this.data>
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next" partialRefresh="true"
            id="pager1" xp:key="viewTitle" for="dynamicViewPanel1">
        </xp:pager>
    </xp:this.facets>
</xe:dynamicViewPanel>
```